# Storing and retrieving the password to form server connection in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with postgres as the database and hibernate as ORM. One of the functionalities of the application is to allow the user to save the credentials(username and password) of an HTTP server(not my spring boot application). After this, the user can select to upload documents to the server. In this case, my application will retrieve the credentials from the database to establish a connection with the server.

My question is: How can I securely store and then use the password for the server? If I store a hashed value, how can use it to login to the server since there is no second password to match the hashed one?

Comment: You can use plaintext and promise users that nobody will look on those passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTP Server does not provide some kind of Token you have to store it in the Database in a way that your application can decrypt it.
This does not have to be plain text but could be e.g. encrypted using a public key (and you store the private key to decrypt it in your application or at least bundled with the application).
Doing that at least someone who only gets access to the database cannot use the information to get Access to the HTTP Server but you have to protect your application (or the private key) then.

See e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography for examples. Java offers everything needed out of the box, see e.g. here for an example: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-asymmetric-cryptography-example/.